# Can people be in several organizations in github?

Tags: github

I've never seen this, but some people may actually belong to several organizations (I do).

I can send a request to be included in one of them (so far I'm in none), but I wouldn't like that to prevent me from joining other organizations and I wouldn't like a future inclusion in another organization pulling me out of the current one (as if it was an update of my current situation or something similar).

Therefore I decided to ask before messing things up, everybody knows I'm in the organizations I am, but I wouldn't like to mess things up and piss people up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can be a part of more than one organization on GitHub. In your [settings for organizations](https://github.com/settings/organizations), you can see which organizations you're a part of, and create your own. If you're invited to an organization, you'll get an e-mail notification.

Each organization has it's own dashboard, and you can switch between them. Read more [here](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations).